# Linker not enough ROM

Tags: c, linker-errors, pic

I'm struggling to fix the following error:

`** Error 71 "FilePath\$linker.c" Line 3(8,14): Out of ROM, A segment or the program is too large    MAIN Seg 000C6-03CBE, 0C3E left, need 00DA2 Seg 00000-00002, 0000 left, need 00DA2 Reserved Seg 00004-00006, 0004 left, need 00DA2 Seg 00008-000C4, 0000 left, need 00DA2 Reserved`

This has been caused, while I have move functions out of *Main.c* as I inherited the code and everything was in *main.c* apart from a few functions that were in some header files, but no other *.c files in the project.

From what I've been able to find out, this is caused by at least one function using more that one page in ROM.

I have tried the following suggestions already:

- Break down functions into more smaller functions
- Optimize code so there is less code where possible

So my questions are:

- Should I just put it all back into main so there is no need for a linker? (This is definitely not ideal for me.)
- If I break it down to smaller *.c files, will that have any effect?
- Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: What device should this fit in? Did you try to enable optimization of the compiler?

Comment: its for a PIC18F8490.

Comment: I've since i did not have optimzation enabled for debug, however i've just built in release and it works. so it must just be all the debug stuff in the code that makes oit too much

Comment: ttry to switch xc8 to large memory model